# Logistic Regression: How to maximize function parameters?

Tags: algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, logistic-regression

I have a Python function **MyFunction (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)** which takes several parameters, then processes some real data and returns a numerical value **x**. If I should be more specific, the function is basically processing a data table with 150000 rows and counting how many rows fulfill certain conditions based on the inputs.

For example MyFunction (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2) returns 79107, MyFunction (1, 3, -1.5545, 7, 3, 1, 3, 15, 1.785, -2.5454) returns 68758 and so on.

How can I find which combination of those 10 parameters a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j gives the maximum possible value of x? Whereas those passed parameters can be any numbers (float/integer) and within any range. X is always in the range 0-150000.

EDIT: Here's the code with data I use if somebody wants to take a look. [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZbKHzkG7_62BP9gOkeTYQZy9ZvUmfT7k#scrollTo=LM4UE3KgVMKL)

Comment: You can call your function for all possible combinations of the parameters `a, b, c, d, e`. In practice though, you need to know something about your function to be able to optimize. What do you know about it?

Comment: See [Optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization).

Comment: Here's the whole code with the data I use. The only difference is 10 params instead of 5 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZbKHzkG7_62BP9gOkeTYQZy9ZvUmfT7k#scrollTo=LM4UE3KgVMKL

Answer (score 0):

I solved my case using the **scipy.optimize.minimize** function. The calculation was very fast, took less than a minute. I'm very surprised at how efficient it is. But I had to try different calculation methods, it's only the method='Powell' that worked like a charm in my case.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def MyFunction (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j):
   #do something
   return x*-1 # because the function is minimize, so x*-1 maximizes it 

StartValues = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

res = minimize (MyFunction, StartValues, method='Powell', tol=0.01)

print (res)
```